# The homogeneity of regression slopes assumption 2 way ANCOVA with 2 covariates in R

Tags: r, ancova

I have a dataset with a DV, 2 IVs(IV1 & IV2) and 2 covariates(CV1 and CV2),
and I want to compare means of the DV with 2-way between-group ANCOVA using the covariates in R.
But I'm not sure how to check the homogeneity of regression slopes assumption in this situation.
I found some sources to do this for 2-way ANCOVA with ONE covariate, but not with two or more.

Should every possible interection term be included to test the assumption?
I mean, if using `aov` function, will

```
aov(DV ~ IV1*IV2*CV1*CV2, data = dataset)
```

check the assumption?

Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: I think my advice would be to not worry if your model is an ancova with homogenous slopes, but to construct a general linear model with whatever variables and interactions are relevant or of interest to you. ...  That being said, CV1:IV1 will test the homogeneity of the slope of CV1 for each level of IV1.  And then CV1:IV2 will test the homogeneity of the slope of CV1 for each level of IV2.  Then you would do the same for CV2.  So you don't quite need all the interactions that would be in the model you propose.

Comment: Thinking more about it, it might make sense to also test each covariate with the interaction of IVs, e.g. CV1 : ( IV1 : IV2 )...

Comment: @SalMangiafico thank you, I really appriciate your comment. I'm sticking with ANCOVA because I want to control the effect of the CVs on the DV by modeling like `lm(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + CV1 + CV2)` . I'm not quite interested in the interactions of IVs*CVs and CV1*CV2, but I think they have to be taken into consideration if they are significant.

Comment: @SalMangiafico thank you for another comment! Unfortunately and interestingly, I've found CV1 : ( IV1 : IV2 ), IV1 : CV1 and IV2 : CV1 significant. Indeed, the data are observational, so this might not be so surprising... but I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: There's no problem if there are significant interactions.  One definition of "ancova" entails that there isn't an interaction between the CV and IV.  But that's just an arbitrary definition.  It's fine to fit a model with whatever terms you are interested in.  Just call it a "general linear model" and don't worry about the definition of "ancova".  ...  But also, don't' focus ***too*** much on p-values.  All they say is that the model can confidently detect an effect relative to the noise in the data.  A significant p-values doesn't necessarily mean a practically important effect.

Comment: @SalMangiafico I want to compare means by condition in a (relatively) simple way because the result will be shared with and be used by those who don't have much knowledge about stats. The p-values are not **very** low, and, more importantly, the effect sizes are small. But now I'm thinking plotting the result is a good way to show what is happening in the dataset in this situation.

Comment: Yes, plotting the results in a way that's clear for the audience sounds good.  One approach would be to run the model and then extract estimated marginal means (emmeans) or least square means (lsmeans), depending on what's available.  These will be the means for the IVs, adjusted for other terms in the model.  You should also be able to get confidence intervals or standard errors for these emmeans.  That makes a nice plot for the audience. And I think it's easy enough to explain to the audience that you built a model with all these covariates and that the model adjusts the results for these.

Comment: A couple of possibilites for plots:  [rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image233.png](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image233.png), [rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image234.png](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image234.png).